# Python Pandas matching closest index from another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df.index = 10,100,1000

df2.index = 1,2,11,50,101,500,1001
Just sample
```

I need to match closest index from df2 compare with df by these conditions

1. df2.index have to > df.index
2. only one closest value

for example output

```
df     |   df2
10     |   11
100    |   101
1000   |   1001
```

Now I can do it with for-loop and it's extremely slow

And I used new_df2 to keep index instead of df2

```
new_df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["value"])
for col in df.index:
    for col2 in df2.index:
        if(col2 > col):
            new_df2.loc[col2] = df2.loc[col2]
            break
        else:
            df2 = df2[1:] #delete first row for index speed
```

How to avoid for-loop in this case Thank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how robust this is, but you can sort `df2` so it's index is decreasing, and use `asof` to find the most recent index label matching each key in `df`'s index:

```
df2.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
df['closest_df2'] = df.index.map(lambda x: df2.index.asof(x))

df
Out[19]: 
      a  closest_df2
10    1           11
100   2          101
1000  3         1001
```

Comment: OMG thank you for this how to handle if the last closest_df2 return NaN then delete that df row